# Why is this direct initialization valid? (C++ 17)

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, c++17

Consider the following two classes:

```
class B
{
public:
   B() { }
   B(const B& b) = delete; //Move ctor not implicitly declared
};


class A
{
public:
   A() { }

   operator B()
   {
       return B();
   }
};
```

I can see why this code compiles fine:

```
A a;
B b = a;
```

Following the rules of [copy-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), the object "a" gets converted to a prvalue of type B and since in C++17 the copy constructor is not needed anymore there's no error:

> If T is a class type, and the cv-unqualified version of the type of
>   other is not T or derived from T, or if T is non-class type, but the
>   type of other is a class type, user-defined conversion sequences that
>   can convert from the type of other to T (or to a type derived from T
>   if T is a class type and a conversion function is available) are
>   examined and the best one is selected through overload resolution. The
>   result of the conversion, which is a prvalue temporary (until
>   C++17)prvalue expression (since C++17) if a converting constructor was
>   used, is then used to direct-initialize the object. The last step is
>   usually optimized out and the result of the conversion is constructed
>   directly in the memory allocated for the target object, but the
>   appropriate constructor (move or copy) is required to be accessible
>   even though it's not used. (until C++17)

However why does this direct list-initialization compile too?

```
A a;
B b{ a };
```

I couldn't find any wording in the [list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) stating the compiler should attempt to convert A into B in this case. Only that overload resolution on constructors is considered:

> If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of T
>   participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that
>   consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction
>   that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed

However in this case the copy constructor is deleted, so shouldn't it not be selected by overload resolution?

Comment: To be clear the copy-constructor is not needed when copy can be accomplished  onlyby reference-copy semantics, it is still necessary to deep copy objects.

Comment: The code `B b{ a.operator B() };` would be fine: initialization from a prvalue of the same type is by temporary materialization into `b`. (dcl.init/17.6.1). But in `B b{a};` the `a` is not a prvalue so I don't think that clause applies and so it should be rejected (dcl.init/17.6.2 - overload resolution applied to constructors)

Comment: The copy-constructor isn't being used , I think the compiler has decided to materialize the temporary from `return B()` into `b`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [CWG 2327](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2327). You're correct as far as the standard goes, but some compilers additionally consider conversion functions in this context as well - because it really makes sense to.

Comment: Indeed the above code worked with gcc and clang, but was rejected by msvc. I guess copy initialization should be preferred in this case with the current standard.